# Appening variable to viewbag name in for each loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a mvc 3 vb.net app that I need to generate several viewbags for... I tried the following code to just drop a variable at the end of the viewbag name after each loop but it wont take it.. It says "Object variable or With block variable not set." when it his the viewbag.status(p) line on the second pass it makes through the loop...

```
     Dim p As Integer = 0
        For Each registrant In b
            Dim _regi As attendance = registrant
            Dim _status As New List(Of String)
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_regi.Completed_Class) Then
                _status.Add(_regi.Completed_Class)
            End If
            _status.Add("--")
            _status.Add("Absent")
            _status.Add("Left Early")
            _status.Add("Completed")
            ViewBag._status(p) = _status
            p = p + 1
        Next
```

And the view looks like this:

```
  @ModelTYPE List(Of xxxxxx.attendance)
  @Code
  ViewData("Title") = "Class Attendance Record"
 End Code
 @Using Html.BeginForm
 @<fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Registrant ID</th>
    <th>Course Status</th>
    <th>Comments</th>

</tr>

 @For r As Integer = 0 To Model.Count - 1
    Dim i As Integer = r
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(i).id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(i).course_ref)



  @<tr>        
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m(i).firstName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(i).firstName)
    </td>

    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m(i).lastName)
         @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(i).lastName)
    </td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m(i).reg_id)
         @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(i).reg_id)
    </td>

    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(m) m(i).Completed_Class, New SelectList(ViewBag._status(i)))
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(i).Completed_Class)
    </td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m(i).Comments, New With {.class = "AttenComment"})
         @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m(i).Comments)
   </td>
</tr>
Next
</table>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" /></p>
</fieldset>
End Using
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply created the viewbag inside the for each loop of my view... So that way everytime it went through the loop to handle each item in the table it would generated that items viewbag for the dropdown as well..

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you've provided, `ViewBag._status` is actually holding a `List(Of List(Of String))`. In other words, each `ViewBag._status(p) is actually holding a List(Of String), and _status is itself a list or array.

I think what will solve your problem is to do all the work first, then set `ViewBag._status` after the loop is finished.

```
Dim statusLists As New List(Of List(Of String))
For Each registrant In b
    Dim _regi As attendance = registrant
    Dim _status As New List(Of String)
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_regi.Completed_Class) Then
        status.Add(_regi.Completed_Class)
    End If
    _status.Add("--")
    _status.Add("Absent")
    _status.Add("Left Early")
    _status.Add("Completed")
    statusLists.Add(_status)
Next
ViewBag._status = statusLists
```

Comment: Please see my edit above where I have included the view so you have a idea of why these need to be unique..

Comment: Ok that part worked... Problem is how do I get those out of the viewbag by index number in a dropdownlistfor

Comment: I actually figured it out... I was thinking to hard into it.. my view was already part of the work